# rolling back version on whole s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, version

I have an s3 bucket on aws with versioning enabled. I need to "rollback" to the previous version. Not file by file but the whole bucket. Is there any software i can use? or any command on the console that i can run? it's an emergency and time sensitive.

Thanks you!

Comment: I added an answer pointing to s3-pit-restore, an open source software which I am not affiliated with, and which is much more useful to a user than the current answer "There is no concept of rollback to the previous version".  it was deleted @MartijnPieters . That package should restore an entire bucket to a point-in-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no concept of "rollback to the previous version" for a bucket.

Each object maintains a version history, and each historical version of each object is maintained and accessible.

If you wish to abandon the most recent version of each object, you would need to write a script/program that would:

- Obtain a list of all objects
- For each object:

  - Obtain a list of versions
  - Delete the most recent version

The prior version of each object would then become the *current* version.

Alternatively, you could obtain the previous version of each object without removing the current version. This would involve a similar script/program, without the delete step.